# How to know if two lines intersects in ZedGraph?

Tags: intersection, zedgraph, intersect, line-intersection

I am using ZedGraph to draw graphs in C#. I have been asked to draw a parabole and a "normal" line in the same graph, and I need to know programatically if the parabole and the line intersect at any point (actually, I have to know that AND if one line is close enough from the other).

Is there a way to know that in ZedGraph?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Analytical solution is inacceptable?